# Fake a client camera for a web application in the desktop browser

Tags: web-applications, browser, mobile, spoofing

I'm testing a web application, where I came across a button. This button is supposed to start the client's camera application and then allow the user to upload a photo.

As I am testing from a virtual machine, there is no camera application and therefore the button simply does nothing for me.

After some research, I believe that the web application is built with/on `cordova`. I do have access to the JavaScript, which I believe, is responsible for the button action - but I can not share the code.

In summary this is what happens:

```
 var client_camera = navigator.camera;
 client_camera.getPicture(...)
```

Is there some way to make the browser/web application think that I do have a camera/camera application and thereby enable the upload of such a picture?

*edit:* [Documentation of the discovered function can be found here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/)

Comment: proposed move to stackoverflow...

Comment: Albeit being relevant for a penetration test, I believe you're right. In hindsight, this would be better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: just call the camera callback directly, mocking an event object w/the props needed for app consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bypass the camera action.

Anyway, `navigator` is an Object contains the client details (browser, OS & some components like camera, flash, etc.)

All I can suggest here is

Check if there is a camera.

If yes, use it.

If not, add a default file uploader

The code

```
if(navigator.camera){
  //camera is there add the code to capture from camera
}
else{
  var file=document.createElement('input');
  file.set attribute('type','file');
  //append it to the container div or body
  // assume that you have a div with class container
 document.querySelector('div.container').appendChild(file);
```

Then you can initiate the upload process while the file is choosen by using a `change` event Handler on the `input` element

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not trying to write an application that handles the scenario, but I'm attempting to spoof a the navigator.camera element on my desktop.

Comment: For that , there is no direct way. you may want to use some third party apps.

Comment: Are you aware of any such third party apps?

Comment: cordova is used for mobile. do you want an android application? then this post may help https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124752/209927 @SaAtomic

Comment: As stated before, I'm trying to spoof the camera on the desktop browser. Firefox on Linux

Comment: so. your virtual platform is browser. not an emulator right. Wait let me check it.

Comment: what did you get while typing `navigator.camera` in the console?

Comment: `var a = navigator.camera;
undefined`

Comment: that's it. browsers didn't have the property. `navigator.camera`. It is specifically for mobile devices only when running in cordova. That is the apache cordova will handle the request.

Comment: Please wait while I try to find a workaround for you.